# Sequences of exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution

> Assume $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d exponential random variables with pdf $\lambda e^{\lambda x}$, and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are i.i.d exponential random variables, independent of $X_i$s, and with pdf $\lambda' e^{\lambda' x}$, where $\lambda'<\lambda$. Calculate
>   $$p_n=\mathbb{P}\left(X_1<Y_1 \bigcap X_1+X_2<Y_1+Y_2 \bigcap \ldots \bigcap  \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\right)$$
>   see if  $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} p_n =c>0$.

I can say:
$$p_n = \mathbb{P}\left(X_1<Y_1\right)  \mathbb{P}\left(X_1+X_2<Y_1+Y_2|X_1<Y_1\right) \ldots \mathbb{P}\left(  \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \leq  \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\bigg|X_1<Y_1 \bigcap X_1+X_2<Y_1+Y_2 \bigcap \ldots \right)$$

But, I am not sure how to continue. Also, if I want to just consider the asymptotic behavior, I can use bounds:
$$p_n\geq \mathbb{P}\left(X_1<Y_1 \bigcap X_2<Y_2 \bigcap \ldots \bigcap  X_n<Y_n\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(X_1<Y_1\right)^n \to 0$$

which did not help. Any idea?

Comment: It looks like a generalization of the Bertrand's ballot problem (http://kurser.math.su.se/pluginfile.php/16103/mod_folder/content/0/2017/2017_04_report.pdf?forcedownload=1.)

Comment: From the problem statement you don't need to compute the probability, rather it seems, you need to bound it. Have you tried anything along these lines?

Comment: @david yes, but it didnt work since i achieved p>=0.

Comment: @david Hi, I just updated the statement to show what I tried for bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of $\sum_{i=1}^j X_i$ as the $j$th arrival of a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$; similarly for $\sum_{i=1}^j Y_i$ and a Poisson process with rate $\lambda'$.

Since these processes are independence, [superposition](http://www.randomservices.org/random/poisson/Splitting.html) implies that you can think of this as a combined Poisson process with rate $\lambda + \lambda'$, and then for each arrival, flip a coin with heads probability $q:=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\lambda'}$; if it is heads, label the arrival "heads," and otherwise label the arrival as "tails." The heads arrivals form the first Poisson process with rate $\lambda$, and the tails arrivals form the Poisson process with rate $\lambda'$.

Thus if you flip a coin with heads probability $q$ repeatedly, then **$p_n$ is the probability that the $j$th heads is before the $j$th tails flip, for each $j=1,\ldots,n$.**

However, I am not sure how to compute this. As noted in the comments, this is similar to Bertrand's ballot problem; see also [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72025/probability-of-always-more-heads-than-tails).